# kafka stream api not generating messages into new topic

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I am running Pipe.java as given in the stream api example here https://kafka.apache.org/20/documentation/streams/tutorial . I am doing exactly as given in the link. Kafka broker is also running on localhost and port 9092.

I have created topics streams-plaintext-input and streams-pipe-output. While I send some messages into topic streams-plaintext-input using kafka-console-producer.sh utility, I do not see any messages coming into topic streams-pipe-output.

Can someone tell me what wrong I am doing?

```
package myapps;

import java.util.Properties;
import java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch;

import org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Serdes;
import org.apache.kafka.streams.KafkaStreams;
import org.apache.kafka.streams.StreamsBuilder;
import org.apache.kafka.streams.StreamsConfig;
import org.apache.kafka.streams.Topology;
import org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.KStream;

public class MyPipe {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put(StreamsConfig.APPLICATION_ID_CONFIG, "mystreams-pipe");
        props.put(StreamsConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "localhost:9092");
        props.put(StreamsConfig.DEFAULT_KEY_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG, Serdes.String().getClass());
        props.put(StreamsConfig.DEFAULT_VALUE_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG, Serdes.String().getClass());
        final StreamsBuilder builder = new StreamsBuilder();
        builder.stream("streams-plaintext-input").to("streams-pipe-output");
        final Topology topology = builder.build();
        System.out.println(topology.describe());
        final KafkaStreams streams = new KafkaStreams(topology, props);
        final CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(1);

        // attach shutdown handler to catch control-c
        Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread("streams-shutdown-hook") {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                streams.close();
                System.out.println("closing");
                latch.countDown();
            }
        });

        try {
            System.out.println("starting stream application.");
            streams.start();

            System.out.println("started");
            latch.await();
        } catch (Throwable e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.exit(1);
        }

        System.out.println("exiting");
        System.exit(0);
    }

}
```

Comment: Share your source code (Pipe.Java)

Comment: @iammehrabalam shared the source code. kindly check

Comment: Did you disable auto topic creation and create the output topic first? Are there any errors logs shown on the actual broker?

Comment: Is there any error in the Streams application logs?